# VBA- input value arbitrarily functions

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with my code sometimes works but sometimes randomly refuses to work and I have no idea why.

I have this source code below and when I input a date and click submit, it's supposed to search the input value in the range of cells. Very strangely, sometimes the code works and sometimes it completely refuses to work and pops out a message box saying 'Value not found'.

```
Option Explicit
'I'm going to let the program search for the date in the pre-filled date -> select the entire row & column below -> move it down by 1 row -> insert the date above the moved pre-filled date -> fill other details
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchValue As Variant
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    
    Set ws = Sheet1 'setting it up so that I'm dealing with Sheet1
    ws.Range("A7:A37").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm" 'setting the number format of the values in A7:A37 as dd-mmm DO NOT CHANGE THIS TO dd-MMM. Keep it as dd-mmm ******
    searchValue = Me.TextBox1.Value 'setting the input value as a variable
    Set searchRange = ws.Range("A7:A37")
    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value found!"
        foundCell.Select
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not found..."
    End If
End Sub
```

Would anyone be able to help me out on this?

Thank you in advance ..

I tried restarting the application, capitalize, not capitalize but once it decides not to work, it refuses any input form.

Comment: You're not specifying many parameters in your `.Find` statement.. so whatever parameters were used (by program or yourself manually) might be applied also, which could explain its erratic behaviour.

Comment: Setting the date number format alone [will not](https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365) change the cell to a date if it wasn't already a date.

Comment: post a shot of your data and of TextBox1.Value that generates the issue: dates are often a PITA in Excel